# Zero crossings around mean

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

I am working on developing a suite classifiers for EEG signals and I will be needing a zero-crossings around mean function, defined in the following manner:

[image]

Ideally if I have some vector with a range of values representing a sinusoid or any time varying signal, I will want to return a vector of Booleans of the same size as the vector saying if that particular value is a mean crossing. I have the following Matlab implementation:

```
ZX = @(x) sum(((x - mean(x)>0) & (x - mean(x)<0)) | ((x - mean(x)<0) & (x - mean(x)>0)));
```

Testing it on toy data:

```
[0 4 -6 9 -20 -5]
```

Yields:

```
0
```

EDIT:
Yet I believe it should return:

```
3
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you come up with the expected result? The sigma will add up everything to one number.

Comment: I made the edit to the desired output to reflect this. It should return the number of times the signal crosses the mean. The original question still stands.

Answer (score 1):

An expression like:

```
((x-m)>0) & ((x-m)<0)
```

is always going to return a vector of all zeros because no individual element of x is both greater and less than zero.  You need to take into account the subscripts on the `x`s in the definition of `ZX`:

```
((x(1:end-1)-m)>0) & ((x(2:end)-m)<0)
```

Comment: Thank you. I also realized that with the test case I have above, it should actually return 3, not 4

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `findpeaks` function on `-abs(x)`, where `x` is your original data, to find the peak locations. This would give you the zero crossings in general for continuous signals which do not have zero as an actual maximum of the signal.

```
t = 0:0.01:10;
x = sin(pi*t);
plot(t,x)
grid

y = -abs(x);
[P,L] = findpeaks(y,t);

hold on
plot(L,P,'*')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use `movprod`, and count the products which are negative, i.e.,

```
cnt = sum(sign(movprod(x-mean(x),2))<0);
```

With your toy example, you will get `cnt = 3`.